# Second border appears when duplicating edge

Tags: edges

I am trying to duplicate an outer edge on the green track, however once I duplicate and separate with <kbd>P</kbd>, the duplicated edge has another border around it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: You most likely have a *Solidify* modifier on your object, but its impossible for us to know for sure from a photo of your monitor.

Comment: Yes I do have a solidly modifier should I apply my modifiers first?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. What is your goal here? Ideally no, modifiers should be kept live and unapplied for as long as possible.

Comment: **Tip:** You can create a screenshot of your window (or parts of it) from the main menu: *Window* > *Save Screenshot*. Another way is to share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: Okay just shared my file I just want to duplicate the outer edge but there’s a double layer that is showing. Thank you

Comment: When you separate with P, the new object inherits a copy of all the modifiers from the original.  If you don't need the solidify mod anymore you can just remove it from the new object.

Comment: You may have shared your file but you still need to put a link to it here so that it can be downloaded!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=kXAm16jS" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kXAm16jS/)

Comment: @AllenSimpson wow thank you so much that worked!